# Regex - Match substring outside of hashtags(#)

Tags: regex, language-agnostic, pcre

Taking this string as an example:

> focus;focus#focus#focus focus

If I want to look for the substring `focus`, I need this result (matches in bold):

> **focus**;**focus**#focus#**focus** **focus**

This is as far as I got: `(?<!#)(focus)(?!#)`, demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/cD8nG4/244).
This pattern obviously does not work because is excluding the substrings next to a `#`, I need those to be included as well.

Programmatically speaking, this is what I need:

```
if !(prefix == "#" && suffix == "#") {
    // Is a match
}
```

Comment: put a lookahead inside the lookbehind: `(?<!#(?=focus#))` or use the backtracking control verb well known sequence: `#focus#(*SKIP)(*F)|focus`

Comment: Avoid the language-agnostic tag in regex questions (even with the pcre or other engine tag) since the supported features may be different between implementations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use an alternation:

```
(?<!#)focus|focus(?!#)
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cD8nG4/245)

Which means match `focus` if not preceded by `#` or not followed by `#`. That will skip `focus` only if it has `#` on both sides.